# How safe is sudo when running from root to run an application as a less privileged user?

Tags: linux, security, sudo

Lets say I am logged in at a root terminal and I run something like the following command:

```
sudo -u '#1000' dbus-launch chromium
```

- Are there any potential security issues I should be worried about?
- Is there a safer way to do it? With the requirement that it works with GUI applications, which **runuser** does not. If I use `runuser` I get `failed to open display`.

With that I can execute terminal commands from my keyboard through custom drivers (g15daemon), which can only be launched as root.

Comment: What privileges does the user with UID 1000 have? If that user is just a usual non-privileged user, then there shouldn't be any security issues. My understanding is that the dbus-launch chromium process will have the same rights as if you had run the command while logged in as that user.

Comment: @Warwick User with UID 1000 is just a usual user in the wheel group. So in theory at least this is just as much safe as it would be to launch it from the user itself?

Comment: You don't need `sudo` for this, you can use `su username -c "command"`.

Comment: Barmar is right. If you are already root, then there is no point in running `sudo`.

Comment: @Barmar You don't need `su` for this. In fact `su` has some serious deficiencies that `sudo` can handle.

Comment: @Patrick He's already doing that. But the point of `sudo` is to allow ordinary users to execute commands as another user, without having to know the root password. If you're already root, you don't need `sudo`, you can just use `su`, which is simpler.

Comment: What deficiencies?

Comment: @Barmar The foremost is argument preservation. If you want to run a command with arguments that require quoting, it becomes very cumbersome. `su -c 'prog1 "arg1 with space" arg2'` vs `sudo prog1 "arg2 with space" arg2`. Though this is just a simple example. When you start chaining/passing commands, this actually becomes **extremely** difficult to handle in a shell script.

Comment: Actually. That was a terrible example. Lets assume you have a shell array `$ARGS`, `su -c "prog1 '${args[@]}'"` won't work. `sudo prog1 "${args[@]}"` will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### sudo

From the relevant man page:

> The real and effective uid and gid are set to match those of the target user as specified in the passwd file.

Also, in the description for the `-P` (preserve group vector) option to sudo:

> The real and effective group IDs, however, are still set to match the target user.

Basically, whatever commands that are run using sudo will be run with the **effective** user and group IDs of the target user.

To answer the question, *“Is there a safer way to do it”*, when running sudo as a non-privileged user, I prefer to use the `-H` (HOME) option to *“set the HOME environment variable to the homedir of the target user”*. Some time in the past I was caught out by some unexpected behaviour (can’t remember the details) which I was able to prevent by adding the `-H` option to shell scripts that used sudo.

You should probably also make sure that the `secure_path` and `env_reset` options are set correctly in your `/etc/sudoers`. Running `sudo -V` shows which environment variables will be passed on to commands launched by sudo and which won’t along with other interesting / useful information.

### su

Alternatively, you can use `su $(id -un 1000) -c 'dbus-launch chromium'` to run Chromium with the effective user id and group id of user #1000.

If you use `su` to accomplish the same task, you should be aware that (by
default) `su` only sets the `HOME` and `SHELL` environment variables to those of
the target user. In this case (where the target user is non-priveleged, i.e., not
a super-user) the `USER` and `LOGNAME` are also set to those of the target user.
The remaining environment variables (such as `PATH`) are preserved.

To avoid leaking any environment data to the non-privileged processes being run,
`su` should be run with the `--login` or `-l` option for a login shell, e.g.
`su $(id -un 1000) -lc 'dbus-launch chromium'`

The `--login` unsets all environment variables except `TERM` and then resets
`HOME`,`SHELL`, `USER` and `LOGNAME` as listed above. In addition the `PATH` is
set to a pre-compiled default value and the current working directory is set to
the target user’s home directory before running the target user’s login script.

I generally prefer sudo over su because of its logging capability and its
“ticketing system” which obviates the need to re-type your password within 5
minutes of the previously successful sudo.

Comment: Thanks, I think I can deduce from this that there are potential security risks associated with ´sudo´, for example you can see here a former [issue with secure_path](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/alerts/secure_path.html) and there is a rather big list of environment variables that is passed on too by default which I know very little about.

Is ´su -c´ really safer? or does it have the same problems?

Comment: I wasn’t aware that you could have different instances of PATH in your environment so I couldn’t say if su is any safer in this regard. BTW, I edited my answer above to add extra info about su and to advocate using `-l` if you choose to use su (I also tried to improve the formatting to make the now longer answer more readable).